# NHibernate Guid generator if new

Tags: nhibernate

I'd like NHibernate to generate guids for entities only if they are not set manually by the user or application. Basically, when saving objects with new Guid() (all zeros), NHibernate should generate one. When saving an object that has a non-zero Guid, it should use that instead.

Is my only option to write my own generator?

**edit** Folks, I'm aware of 'assigned'. I should have specified I was aware of it. Since it doesn't do what I want it to do, it's not the option I'm looking for. Writing my own generator is an option that works, but I'd like something else. I'm suspecting there is nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that NH needs to know if the object is new or if it already exists. It does this usually by setting the ID.

If you wrote your own generator, it doesn't solve the problem, because it is only called if the object is new.

- You could use the `assigned` generator.
- You could use a version column to indicate if the object is new. I never tried it this way, but it should work. NOT having any indication for NH if the object is new causes quite some troubles. Believe me.
- You could also have a integer as primary key and the GUID as regular unique field.

I whould generate the id in the class' constructor

```
class Entity
{
  Guid id;

  Entity(Guid id = Guid.Empty)
  {
    if (id == Guid.Empty) this.id = Guid.NewGuid();
    else this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't follow. The object IS new. I just want to allow my user code to manually set the Id value, before calling Save. Just like 'assigned', except it needs to ALSO work if Id == Guid.Zero

Comment: If you want to assign the ID in the user code, you need to use "assigned". If you want to create an id when the user code does not assign it, just do this in the constructor of the object. It's as simple as that.

Comment: Stefan, it would be, except I want to do both.

Comment: What's the problem with creating the id in the constructor?

Comment: @StefanSteinegger I think the problem there is the absolute randomness. GuidComb has a semi-sequential nature that, if I understand correctly, could have some insertion performance improvement since it's likely to insert at the end of the table and not somewhere in the middle every time. https://nhibernate.info/blog/2009/05/21/using-the-guid-comb-identifier-strategy.html

Comment: @Reasurria: GuidComb or the issue it solves wasn't mentioned at all so far. I guess the OP wasn't happy with the class that has to care about the ID and wanted something where NHibernate is doing it behind the scenes.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger Fair enough. Guess I was projecting my own requirements onto the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting the `unsaved-value` attribute?

```
<id name="Id" column="Id" type="Guid" unsaved-value="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000">
  <generator class="guid.comb" />
</id>
```

**edit** now I understand your question fully another option instead of rolling out your own generator is to use

```
<generator class="assigned" />
```

However you cannot use `SaveOrUpdate()`. Instead you have to explicitly specify to NHibernate if the object should be saved or updated by calling either the Save() or Update() method of the ISession. Also you will always need to set the GUID manually on all your NEW entities. Its an option.

Comment: No, I haven't. I do not believe that would work as it would consider a non-0 value as saved. Which it might not be. Since I want to create a Guid myself. I will be setting non-0 values on Id.